How to install a languagepack for Mozilla Thunderbird using Windows CLI (Powershell) only?
I'm trying to install a (Ukrainian) language pack for Mozilla Thunderbird command line only. I tried the following but without success. Also, I manually got that xpi URL and I really hope there is a better way to avoid future version incompatbilities. I'm installing the latest Thunderbird using winget. Is there a way to do this in winget or afterwards?
# Define the URL and download path for the Ukrainian language pack
$url = "https://addons.thunderbird.net/thunderbird/downloads/latest/tb-langpack-uk/addon-988016-latest.xpi"
$dest = "C:\langpack-uk.xpi"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $dest

# Assuming the default installation path for Thunderbird
$thunderbirdPath = "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe"

# Open the .xpi file with Thunderbird
Start-Process -FilePath $thunderbirdPath -ArgumentList "$dest"



"...but without success." What did happen when this was run? Please copy/paste, as text, any error messages into the question. No pictures.

For ThunderBird Extensions (also packaged as xpi files), newer versions load the contents of the .xpi file itself on startup (older versions extract the .xpi to a folder from a value in the manifest file) - i expect language packs work in the same way. Theres a fair chance dropping the xpi into the right folder will cause it to get loaded on TB startup. If you rename the .xpi to .zip and pass it to Expand-Archive - you can view the folder structure and the JSON manifest. Installed language packs will probably live under c:\ProgramData or %APPDATA% of your user
